# вложенный контейнер set с пользовательским компаратором

Tags: c++, c++11, map, set

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::function<bool(const int& lhs, const int& rhs)> comparator
    {
        [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs) -> bool
        {
            return lhs > rhs;
        }
    };

    std::map<std::string, std::set<int, decltype(comparator)>> data;

    data["first"].insert(1);
    data["first"].insert(1);
}
```

Как в такую связку, где контейнер std::set создаётся неявно, добавить кастомный компаратор?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы не было ненужного оверхеда, я бы не использовал `std::function` в качестве компаратора, если вам не нужно выбирать один из нескольких компараторов во время выполнения.

В C++20 все просто. Лямбды без списка захвата стали default-constructible, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
auto comparator = [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs) -> bool
{
    return lhs > rhs;
};

std::map<std::string, std::set<int, decltype(comparator)>> data;
```

До C++20 можно написать класс с перегруженным `()` и использовать его как компаратор.

Answer (score 5):

В С++ до С++20 - не хотите просто воспользоваться стандартным компаратором? :)

https://ideone.com/6w9Zmd

```
map<string, set<int,greater<int>>> data;
data["first"].insert(1);
data["first"].insert(2);
data["first"].insert(7);
data["first"].insert(0);

for(auto x: data["first"])
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Или обойтись без лямбды:

```
struct Comps
{
    bool operator()(const int& lhs, const int& rhs)
    {
        return lhs > rhs;
    }
};

map<string, set<int,Comps>> data;

... // Дальше все точно так же
```

Если не использовать `[]`, то можно так (при этом множество создается явно для вставки с данным ключом):

```
int main()
{
    auto compar = [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){ return lhs > rhs; };

    map<string, set<int,decltype(compar)>> data;

    data.insert(make_pair("first",compar));
    data.at("first").insert(1);
    data.at("first").insert(2);
    data.at("first").insert(7);
    data.at("first").insert(0);

    for(auto x: data.at("first"))
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: стандартный нельзя - пример сильно упрощён, до с++20 без структуры никак? хотелось бы именно пульнуть туда лямбду, но я так понимаю, что без default-constructible лямбд и функторов это никак не сделать?

Comment: Ну, а такой вариант не сойдет, как добавлено в ответ?

Comment: к сожалению, нет, сделаю через объект. Спасибо)

Comment: @Harry а разве operator() не должен не модифицирующим ? а то будет error: static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const

Comment: @Maggot Ну, я компилировал VC++2017, компилировалось и работало.

Comment: @Harry gcc10 std=c++2a факапится

Comment: @Maggot Вот еще https://ideone.com/GOOaBz Больше мне особо проверять нечем...

Comment: @Harry gcc фича видимо c 8 мажора - https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/porting_to.html : The associative containers (std::map, std::multimap, std::set, and std::multiset) now use static assertions to check that their comparison functions support the necessary operations. In C++17 mode this includes enforcing that the function can be called when const-qualified:

Comment: @Harry на 142 msvc непонятно..... у вас 17 это какой msvс?

Comment: @Maggot `Оптимизирующий компилятор Microsoft (R) C/C++ версии 19.16.27040` (который 15.9.23)